# TChart Error series is not being displayed correctly

Tags: teechart

In one of my windows application, wherein I am using TChart for .Net 2010, I am displaying a chart with 3 error series on it. Each of these series have 2 points. X points for all these series are identical. 
e.g. Series1 has Point1(x1=0.2, bar=0, StdErr=5) & Point2(x1=0.6, bar=1, StdErr=8) whereas Series2 has Point1(x1=0.2, bar=0, StdErr=8) & Point2(x1=0.6, bar=1, StdErr=10).

The expected chart should display overlapped error bars at 2 locations  0.2 and 0.6 on x axis. But in fact, it displaying error bars with sufficient separation between them.

Is this a problem with TChart or do I need to have some settings to overlap these error bars? Please let me know if anyone has solution for it.

thanks,
kapil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a TeeChart problem but default behaviour. All series deriving from *Steema.TeeChart.Styles.CustomBar* class have *MultiBar* property which lets the programmer choose how bars will be plotted in such circumstances. By default *MultiBar* is set to *Steema.TeeChart.Styles.MultiBars.Side*. Setting it to *Steema.TeeChart.Styles.MultiBars.None* solves your problem, for example:

```
  tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    Steema.TeeChart.Styles.ErrorBar errorBar = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.ErrorBar(tChart1.Chart);
    errorBar.MultiBar = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.MultiBars.None;
    errorBar.FillSampleValues();
  }
```

If that's not what you were looking for you can try with different *MultiBar* settings and let us know if it still doesn't fit your needs.